# In Safari on macOS, when I close a tab, how can I get focus on the previously focused tab

Tags: safari, tabs, focus

The default behavior is to focus the tab to the right of the closed tab (or the tab to the left if the closed tab was the right-most tab).

How can I get focus on the previously focused tab?

Comment: Actually, the default is to focus back on the tab that was previously focussed, *if that tab was the 'source' from which the current URL was launched*. Otherwise, it behaves as you describe.

Comment: That nuance is interesting. But what I want is to _always_ go back to the previously focused one.

Comment: I doubt it enumerates that way, tbh. From a link it has a chain of actions, simply switching tabs doesn't really have the same requirements. Wish you luck, in case someone knows a way.